# How to make a custom function code for excel to sum the arrays from multiple columns

Tags: javascript, custom-functions-excel

I'm setting up a google sheet/excel sheet for my mother. To give an example of how she tallies her business goods manually, here below is what she does every day: 
                 [Hotel1    Hotel2          Total Tomatoes for Hotel
(e.g. Tomatoes (1+1+1+4)   (1+2+2+1)                    13](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWFft.png)

Note that this is only an example; she tallies more approximately more than 13 hotels, making it an estimate of 11 more columns containing arrays with (+).

To be completely honest, I really want to help her with this by making her works digitalized, wherein she will tally through an excel sheet for less effort. Unfortunately, my skills are limited to simple basic functions. And as for her ability, she can type manually like the one above (e.g. 2+2+4+5). I planned on summing the digits individually and counting the (+) sign as to be read as an addition function but I don't know-how. I really want to help her honestly, I tried my best really but I'm just good with coding. So to any good soul out there who wants to lend a hand, please message me and help me this. I would appreciate it very much.

I tried searching for examples and learning basic standard JavaScript but I can't seem to get a grasp of it

Array (

```
[0] => Array ( [f_count] => 1 [uid] => 105 ) 
[1] => Array ( [f_count] => 0 [uid] => 106 ) 
[2] => Array ( [f_count] => 2 [uid] => 107 ) 
[3] => Array ( [f_count] => 0 [uid] => 108 ) 
[4] => Array ( [f_count] => 1 [uid] => 109 ) 
[5] => Array ( [f_count] => 0 [uid] => 110 ) 
[6] => Array ( [f_count] => 3 [uid] => 111 )
```

)

I don't claim that I made this but this is the closest I can find online.

I am too stupid to understand and solve my own problems.

Comment: I noticed that you want to use JavaScript.  Is there a reason why you don't just use normal spreadsheet functions?

Answer (score 0):

Hi I would agree with the point that you can use normal worksheet functions. Excel has some great “basics” templates you can try available on the start screen. Likewise there is some good training on support.office.com.  Also, Excel’s powerful tool with many capabilities so I think getting a lay of the land there will help you understand where you can enhance the built in functions with your own.

The Autosum feature is also a great way to learn about functions in excel: https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/use-autosum-to-sum-numbers-543941e7-e783-44ef-8317-7d1bb85fe706